# Data Binding in UWP doesn't refresh

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to bind the 'Text' property of my TextBlock in xaml to a global string, but when I change the string the TextBlock's content doesn't change. What is that I'm missing?

**My xaml:**

```
<StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Change!" Click="Button_Click" />
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind text}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**My C#:**

```
    string text;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        text = "This is the original text.";
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        text = "This is the changed text!";
    }
```

Comment: This will never update since you are not raising the PropertyChanged event. in order to update it, create a DTO that will be static, and have the string inside of it. the static Dto need to implement the NotifyProperty changed.

Comment: when itemsource wont refresh you may try this solution: [Here is Relevant Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47634971/2036103)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default binding mode for `x:Bind` is `OneTime` rather then `OneWay` that was de-facto the default for `Binding`. Furthermore `text` is `private`. To have a working binding you need to have a `public property`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Text , Mode=OneWay}" />
```

And in code-behind

```
private string _text;
public string Text
{ 
    get { return _text; }
    set
    {
        _text = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Text");
    }
```

> Plus it is important to raise PropertyChanged in the setter of Text.

Comment: have you implemented [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: 'raise PropertyChanged in the setter of Text' what do you mean by that?

Comment: Maybe you'll consider my next question stupid but I haven't used the getter and the setter before much. I get the "does not exist in this context" error for the _text and the NotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @MarkUivari that is because the `_text` field is not existing and you do not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Just create a string field _text and implment the interface as shown in the link I provided above.

Comment: Well it took me awhile but I got it to work. Thank you.

Comment: You're kidding me. What an absurd choice for a default. Who would have expected that the default behavior for a binding would be non-dynamic. Thanks for saving me probably an hour of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use it like this when you're in code behind anyways (I'm not sure about .Text maybe it's .Content just try it out):

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtSomeTextBlock/>

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    txtSomeTextBlock.Text = "This is the original text.";
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtSomeTextBlock.Text = "This is the changed text!";
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly too, but I want to understand why the version with the binding doesn't, and how to do it properly.

Answer (score -2):

When databinding via Itemsource not refresh even source is modified [this may solve refresh problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47634971/2036103)