# How to update the GridView after binded itemsource is updated in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to refresh the GridView when values changed in the List collection. Actually I have bind the List as itemsource for the GridView. Where i have changed the List values but which could not relected in the GridView. How to acheive this in UWP?

Comment: Use Observablecolllection instead of List and Implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 2):

use ObserableListCollection

and

```
yourGridviewOrListview1.ItemsSource = null;
yourGridviewOrListview1.ItemsSource = SingletonClass.YourObList;
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the GridView if entries in your list are added, removed or moved you should use an [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of a List.

To update GridView entries if properties of the list entries change the class of your list entries needs to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://danrigby.com/2015/09/12/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-6-way/) and also use databinding in the templates the GridView uses to display your list entries.